# Can I perform Arithmetic in an SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm building a search function for my companies databases, one of the required criteria is an age search, can I build this into a MySQL query? the patients age is calculated at the time of booking (appointment date - DOB), I'm using the latest codeigniter framework, I've tried a few variations of this:

```
$this->db->where("'" . 'app_date' . "' " . '-' . " '" . 'dob' . "' " . "=" . $age);
```

This outputs the following query if I use `echo $this->db->last_query()`:

```
SELECT
    `book_all`.`pin`, `book_all`.`clinic`, `book_all`.`order_date`,
    `book_all`.`app_date`, `book_all`.`dob`, `book_all`.`gender`,
    `book_all`.`country`
FROM `book_all`
WHERE 'app_date' - 'dob' = 34
```

I do calculate the patients age for the output, but the information in the db is stored as two different types: `order_date` is a datetime (Y-m-d h-i-s) and `dob` is a date (Y-m-d).

Ican do a foreach on the resulting array and unset any indexes that dont equal `$age` but its quite a large database so it uses alot of memory and slows down the execution time:

```
$age_count = 0;
foreach ($query as &$val) {
    if ($val['patient_age'] === intval($_POST['age'])) {
       $age_count++;
    } else {
       unset($query[$age_count]);
       $age_count++;
    }
}
```

returns 3 records (correct) however is there a better way to do this? Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: 'app_date' is a string. You cannot substract a string from another string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions specifically for what you are trying to do, especially `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. Please consult the manual here, which has a specific example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-calculations.html

MySQL also has date format functions similar to PHP. Example:

```
DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%H:%i:%s')
```

As long as it can read your source format.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't read your answer properly before I posted mine (essentially the same) . Have an upvote.

Comment: Thankyou! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT x.pin
     , x.clinic
     , x.order_date
     , x.app_date
     , x.dob
     , x.gender
     , x.country
  FROM book_all x
 WHERE x.app_date - INTERVAL 34 YEAR = x.dob
```

This may not be exactly what you want, but it demonstrates the concept. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)